# Solving a multiple variable system of congruences using the Chinese Remainder theorem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

I've tried to solve the following system:

$2x+7y\equiv17\mod35\\3x+8y\equiv18\mod35$

My idea was using the Chinese Remainder theorem, so firstly, I've found that

$3\cdot 5 - 2\cdot 7 = 1$

And that $15$ is $1\mod7$, $\space -14\equiv 1\mod5$.

I'm not sure how to proceed from this point, and I'd like to receive a little help.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you first tried to basically treat the system as just $2$ linear equations in $2$ unknowns to, for example, eliminate $x$ to get $y$ in terms of a value modulo $35$, and then substitute this into the first equation to get $x$?

Comment: CRT won't be useful for this problem. Use John's idea.

Comment: @Ludwig You're welcome. One thing I found when I tried it is that I got multiple results for $y$, in particular $5$ of them, so be aware of that.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Thank you, it was really helpful!

Comment: @Ludwig You're welcome. An alternative to what I suggested earlier is to note from the first equation that $2x \equiv 17 \pmod{7}$, from which you get a result for $x$ modulo $7$ and, thus, $5$ results for $x$ modulo $35$ (I originally suggested, in my now deleted comment, multiplying both sides by $5$, but this is simpler & more direct). You can then use the second equation to get all of the corresponding values of $y$.

Comment: Perhaps a bit simpler way is to subtract one congruence from the other and get $x+y \equiv 1 \pmod{35}$. Now use $x=1-y$ in (say) the first congruence to get $5y \equiv 15 \pmod{35} \implies y \equiv 3 \pmod{7}$. So $y \equiv 3,10,17,24,31 \pmod{35}$.

Comment: @Ludwig One thing to be careful of if you use my idea of $2x \equiv 17 \pmod{7}$ is you should check all of the values of $y$ obtained from the second equation also work in the first one. The issue is with the congruence values modulo $5$ matching. This doesn't cause any problems with this particular set of values since, if you consider the first equation modulo $5$, you get $2x + 2y \equiv 2 \pmod{5} \implies x + y \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$, which matches the second one which is $3x + 3y \equiv 3 \pmod{5} \implies x + y \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$. However, it's something you should be aware of in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subtracting the first congruence from the second gives

$$ x+y \equiv 1\pmod{35}. $$

Using this in the first congruence gives

$$ 17 \equiv 2(x+y) + 5y \equiv 2+5y \pmod{35}, $$

so that $35 \mid 5(y-3)$, or $7 \mid (y-3)$. From $y \equiv 3\pmod{7}$ and $x+y \equiv 1\pmod{7}$ we get $x \equiv 5\pmod{7}$.

The two congruences are identical modulo $5$; they both give $x+y \equiv 1\pmod{5}$. Thus, there are five pairs $(x\bmod{5},y\bmod{5})$ from the two congruences, as opposed to the unique $(x\bmod{7},y\bmod{7})=(5,3)$ for congruences modulo $7$. Therefore, we have following five solutions $(x\bmod{35},y\bmod{35})$.

Set $x=7a+5$, $y=7b+3$, $a,b \in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$. Then $5 \mid (x+y-1)$ reduces to $5 \mid 7(a+b+1)$, and hence to $5 \mid (a+b+1)$ since $\gcd(5,7)=1$. This yields the following pairs $(a,b)$:

$$ (0,4), \quad (1,3), \quad (2,2), \quad (3,1), \quad (4,0). $$

The corresponding pairs $(x\bmod{35},y\bmod{35})$ are

$$ (5,31), \quad (12,24), \quad (19,17), \quad (26,10), \quad (33,3). $$

Comment: Thank you! There's one thing I didn't understand:
How do you deduce that there're 5 pairs (here: "The two congruences are identical modulo 5; they both give x+y≡1(mod5). Thus, there are five pairs")?
I'm probably missing something.

Comment: If $m,n$ are positive and coprime, and there are $r$ choices modulo $m$ and $s$ choices modulo $n$, then there are $rs$ choices modulo $mn$, by Chinese Remainder Theorem (CRT). This is because each pair $(x\bmod{m},y\bmod{n})$ gives rise to a unique $z\bmod{mn}$, and conversely. In this case there is a unique choice modulo $7$ and five choices modulo $5$.